# Merge the "form" and "forms" tags

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Both the tags were used for questions about forms. [form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form) should be merged with [forms](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forms), and made its synonym. Generally, the plural form is preferred; also, in this case it better suits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was only one form question so I just retagged it.